# How to scroll in an Android app with Appium 1.6.4 in C# with windows?

Tags: c#, android, appium

I am trying to scroll in an Android App but I'm getting an error.

Code :

```
Dictionary<string, string> scrollObject = new Dictionary<string, string>();
scrollObject.Add("direction", "down");
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);

Error: System.NotImplementedException: Method has not yet been implemented
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   at AppiumTesting2.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Are you trying to just scroll down or to an element? Also are you using iOS Simulator for iOS 7 or 8?

Comment: Hello kirbycop,

I'm can either scroll to an element or just scroll down to half the page.
I'm using a real Android device with Nougat 7.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

The Swipe, ScrollTo, and ScrollToExact methods have been deprecated. The 2.0.0.1 release notes suggests using `OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.ByAndroidUIAutomator` or `OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.ByIosUIAutomation`. Here is their [example](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/blob/master/integration_tests/Android/AndroidElementTest.cs#L88):

```
[Test]
public void ScrollingToSubElement()
{
    driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Views").Click();
    AndroidElement list = driver.FindElement(By.Id("android:id/list"));
    var locator = new ByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("
                    + "new UiSelector().text(\"Radio Group\"));");
    AppiumWebElement radioGroup = list.FindElement(locator);
    Assert.NotNull(radioGroup.Location);
}
```

As an alternative, a different approach (which is similar to the one you were trying) is presented on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251731/1106708).

```
WebElement element = driver.findElementByXpath("xpath_of_element");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```